# I have few confussion also how to find solo scale from my progression

Tags: electric-guitar, scales, chord-progressions

I am progressing chords for riff

Chords: E5 - F5 - G5

E5 = with Palm Mute

F5 = Normal

G5 = Normal

Pattern:

```
A -2-2----2-2-2--3
E -0-0----0-0-0--1
  P.M-------P.M-
```

it's sound like heavy music but i added vocal like black metal i.e Behemoth.So i can't understand about this Genre :p .One more thing i want to know about that in this chords progression which scale should i choose for solo and let me know if i have to add chords for riff.Thank you.